# issue with pre-defined execution order of fflib unit of work

Tags: apex, fflib

The commitWork() method in the class fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork has a predefined order of execution that always sends the emails at last, as it can be seen as follows:

```
private void doCommitWork()
{
        onCommitWorkStarting();
        onPublishBeforeEventsStarting();
        publishBeforeEventsStarting();
        onPublishBeforeEventsFinished();

        onDMLStarting();
        insertDmlByType();
        updateDmlByType();
        deleteDmlByType();
        emptyRecycleBinByType();
        resolveEmailRelationships();
        onDMLFinished();

        onDoWorkStarting();
        doWork();
        onDoWorkFinished();
        onCommitWorkFinishing();
}  

private void doWork()
{
        m_workList.add(m_emailWork);
        for (IDoWork work : m_workList)
        {
            work.doWork();
        }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/sfdx-source/apex-common/main/classes/fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.cls)

I would like to send the emails first and then execute the update DML. Is this possible? I would like to send an email with the state of the objects before updating the objects but with the fflib unit of work I am forced to always send the emails at last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue in the fflib/apex-common repo](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-common/issues/129) to address this

When I had this issue, I implemented everything in my `IDoWork` worker so I could get the order I wanted.

Comment: Hi, that is great. One thing, I see that the method fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.registerWork is used to register pieces of work but I do not see any method to retrieve the pieces of work. How Do you retrieve the pieces of work registered using fflib_SObjectUnitOfWork.registerWork?

Comment: You can't. And in theory, you shouldn't need to.  The objects presented to registerXXX are your application's objects so the application should keep track of which ones are new v dirty v deleted.